# Vulkan error: Cannot submit cmd buffer using deleted buffer 0x0

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

When submitting work to my graphics queue this way:

```
void Renderer::Render() {
  VkSemaphore wait_semaphore = vulkan()->image_available_semaphore();
  VkSemaphore signal_semaphore = vulkan()->rendering_finished_semaphore();
  VkPipelineStageFlags wait_stage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
  VkCommandBuffer cmd_buff =
    vulkan()->graphics_queue_cmd_buffers()[current_swapchain_img_];
  VkSubmitInfo submit_info = tools::inits::SubmitInfo();
  submit_info.waitSemaphoreCount = 1U;
  submit_info.pWaitSemaphores = &wait_semaphore;
  submit_info.pWaitDstStageMask = &wait_stage;
  submit_info.commandBufferCount = 1U;
  submit_info.pCommandBuffers = &cmd_buff;
  submit_info.signalSemaphoreCount = 1U;
  submit_info.pSignalSemaphores = &signal_semaphore;

  VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkQueueSubmit(
      vulkan()->device().graphics_queue().queue,
      1U,
      &submit_info,
      nullptr));
}
```

I get the following error from the validation layers:

```
Cannot submit cmd buffer using deleted buffer 0x0.
```

Repeated for 10 times.

My cmd buffers are generated this way:

```
void Renderer::SetupCommandBuffers(const VulkanDevice &device) {
  // Cache common settings to all command buffers 
  VkCommandBufferBeginInfo cmd_buff_begin_info =
    tools::inits::CommandBufferBeginInfo(
        VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT);
  cmd_buff_begin_info.pInheritanceInfo = nullptr;

  std::vector<VkClearValue> clear_values;
  VkClearValue clear_value;
  clear_value.color = {{0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f}};
  clear_values.push_back(clear_value);
  clear_value.color = {{1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f}};
  clear_values.push_back(clear_value);
  clear_value.depthStencil = {1.f, 0U};
  clear_values.push_back(clear_value);

  VkImageSubresourceRange image_subresource_range;
  image_subresource_range.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
  image_subresource_range.baseMipLevel = 0U;
  image_subresource_range.levelCount = 1U;
  image_subresource_range.baseArrayLayer = 0U;
  image_subresource_range.layerCount = 1U;

  // Record command buffers
  const std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> &graphics_buffs =
    vulkan()->graphics_queue_cmd_buffers();
  uint32_t num_swapchain_images = vulkan()->swapchain().GetNumImages();
  for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < num_swapchain_images; i++) {
    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBeginCommandBuffer(
        graphics_buffs[i], &cmd_buff_begin_info));

    VkRenderPassBeginInfo render_pass_begin_info =
      tools::inits::RenderPassBeginInfo();
    render_pass_begin_info.renderPass = render_pass_;
    render_pass_begin_info.framebuffer = framebuffers_[i];
    render_pass_begin_info.renderArea = {0U, 0U, kWindowWidth, kWindowHeight};
    render_pass_begin_info.clearValueCount = SCAST_U32(clear_values.size());
    render_pass_begin_info.pClearValues = clear_values.data();

    vkCmdBeginRenderPass(graphics_buffs[i], &render_pass_begin_info,
                         VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

    vis_store_material_.BindPipeline(graphics_buffs[i],
                                     VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS);

    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(
        graphics_buffs[i],
        VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
        pipe_layout_vis_,
        0U,
        SCAST_U32(desc_sets_.size()),
        desc_sets_.data(),
        0U,
        nullptr);

    fullscreenquad_->BindVertexBuffer(graphics_buffs[i]);  
    fullscreenquad_->BindIndexBuffer(graphics_buffs[i]);  

    vkCmdDrawIndexed(
        graphics_buffs[i],
        6U,
        1U,
        0U,
        0U,
        0U);

    // Fullscreen quad
    vkCmdNextSubpass(graphics_buffs[i], VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

    vis_shade_material_.BindPipeline(graphics_buffs[i],
                                     VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS);

    fullscreenquad_->BindVertexBuffer(graphics_buffs[i]);  
    fullscreenquad_->BindIndexBuffer(graphics_buffs[i]);  

    vkCmdDrawIndexed(
        graphics_buffs[i],
        6U,
        1U,
        0U,
        0U,
        0U);

    vkCmdEndRenderPass(graphics_buffs[i]);

    VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkEndCommandBuffer(graphics_buffs[i]));
  }
}
```

Having tried to debug it for a while, commenting out the `vkCmdDrawIndexed` calls removes the error report. I have noticed that removing only one draw call reduces the list of error report from 10 to 5.
Also, even when the error is reported, rendering happens correctly anyway.

I have checked with my debugger that all the values I am passing to the functions are not VK_NULL_HANDLE or uninitialised variables, and that my cmd buffers exist; in fact, the validation layers don't throw any errors when I build the command buffers.

Moreover, I made sure that the list of per-framebuffer-image cmd buffers
exists fully and I am not getting a simple Segfault because of uninitialised vector members.

I cannot figure out the relationship between this error report and the building of the command buffers, so I'd really appreciate if you could help me.
Thanks in advance to anyone.

Comment: The Validation Errors tend to avalanche sometimes (only one being "real" and the rest a consequence of the first error). Are all of the 10 the same error you posted above?

Comment: It is about some/any `VkBuffer` used. Make sure the bound Vertex and Index buffer (and possibly others I can't see from your sample) is still alive when `vkQueueSubmit` is called and until it ends (which is **not** when it returns — but when the `fence` is signalled).

Comment: @krOoze Thank you so much for the tip; I will check that and report.

Comment: @krOoze I've found out the culprit and it was a global variable which was erroneously set for both the vertex buffer and the vertex buffer descriptor which I use to read the vertex buffer in a later render pass, only that the two bindings should have obviously been unrelated. Thanks for the pointer again, it really helped!

Comment: Good. I will make some version of the comments into answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot submit cmd buffer using deleted buffer 0x0.

This error is logged when **any** of the `VkBuffer` objects (not Command buffers though) used by the `vkQueueSubmit` (that is any recorded in the submitted Command buffer(s) ) is already destroyed (or perhaps not created yet). In this case seems to be `VK_NULL_HANDLE` even.

Remember `vkQueueSubmit` is asynchronous. The buffers need to be alive for the duration of `vkQueueSubmit` **and** after that too until the `fence` is signalled (or e.g. `vkDeviceWaitIdle`).

In this code sample I see only two `VkBuffer`s used. The bound vertex and index buffer. And as it turned out it was tied to the vertex buffer (see Question comments for details).

As any good validator, its error messages are often unreadable to puny humans.
But Validation Layers are open source in Khronos repository:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/tree/master/layers

It can help to look there to interpret any error messages that prove to be hard to decipher. Usually (but not always) the error message is in [core_validation.cpp](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/layers/core_validation.cpp)
 (being implementation of the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation` layer).